# no module named pywin32, while importing

Tags: download, libraries, pywin32

I'm trying to install pywin32 library for python. I managed to download pygame the same way I'm trying pywin32. Command prompt says it was succesfully installed but when I try importing it. It says there is no module named pywin32. Can anybody help me?

[image]

Comment: I found an answer. i just had to do "import pywintypes" instead of "import pywin32".

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the Reviews here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/reviews

Highest Rated

I had trouble when I installed pywin32-219.win32-py3.5 on my Surface 3 with Windows 10. I use Python 3.5.0 (32 bit) so the installer was the right one. When I ran the installer, it said it could not find Python 3.5 in the registry. The installer did not show any Python installation to choose from. Luckily I found how to deal with it. When I looked into the registry, the registry key was:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\3.5-32

I renamed the last key from 3.5-32 to 3.5, and ran the installer again, 
then it worked. After installing it, I renamed the key back to 3.5-32 
(When I installed Python 3.5, I chose 'install for all users'. 
The registry key may not be the same as above with the 'install 
for the current user' option) Hope this helps those who are having 
the same trouble.

Good Luck, hope this helps.